# Le COD dans une phrase avec "que"

Tags: conjugaison

Comment s'écrit la phrase :

> J’ai fait les corrections que vous avez demandées ce matin.

ou

> J’ai fait les corrections que vous avez demandé ce matin.

Le mot **demandées** est différent en fonction du COD, qui je crois, est **les corrections**, mais **demandées** s'accord avec "vous" ou "les corrections" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> J’ai fait les corrections que vous avez demandées ce matin.

Car l'auxilliaire est avoir et le COD (les corrections) est placé avant celui-ci (avez).

(La règle exacte est: "Le participe passé des verbes conjugués avec l’auxiliaire avoir s’accorde en genre et en nombre avec le complément direct si celui-ci est placé avant le verbe.")

On écrirait par contre:

> Vous avez demandé des corrections ce matin.

Comment: Il n'y aurait pas d'accord non plus dans *J’ai fait les corrections que vous avez demandé de finir ce matin*.

Answer (score 0):

Au passé composé avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*, le participe passé ne s'accorde pas avec le sujet mais avec le COD s'il est placé avant le verbe.

Dans ta phrase, le COD du verbe *demander* est *les corrections*, repris par *que* ; il est placé avant donc tu vas accorder le participe passé => *demandées*.

Comment: Demande-t-on des corrections ou sous-entend-on demander [(d'en faire)](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1861) ?