# L'accord du participe passé avec l'auxiliaire avoir

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé, antécédent

Quelle est la forme correcte de la phrase suivante et pourquoi ?

> *Je cherche le nombre de pommes qu'il a mang**ées*** (antécédent: **pommes**)

ou

> *Je cherche le nombre de pommes qu'il a mang**é*** (antécédent: **le nombre** de pommes)

Comment: Si je suis votre raisonnement, ce serait pas la première qui serait correcte ? L'antécédent du pronom relatif, c'est "le nombre de pommes" ou "les pommes" ?

Comment: Sauf pour ceux qui mangent trop de nombres, l'accord correct est bien celui du premier exemple ! (@Frank)

Comment: C'est la sémantique qui est pertinente pour trouver l'accord correct. Exemple1: *le panier de pommes qu'il a rempli* vs *le panier de pommes qu'il a cueillies*. Example 2 : *le nombre de pommes qu'il a estimé* vs *le nombre de pommes qu'il a mangées*. @Jiliagre : +1.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est ce que je voulais dire? J'ai pris peur et j'ai rétracté mon commentaire, donc je ne peux plus voir ce que j'avais écrit, mais oui, c'est la première.

Comment: @Frank Ouais ouais, [destruction de preuves...](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006418608) ça risque d'aller loin tout ça ! ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Le COD dans une phrase avec "que"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44844/le-cod-dans-une-phrase-avec-que)

Comment: @guillaume31 Le cas particulier de la question (détermination de l'antécédent) n'est pas abordé dans la question proposée. Les phrases *J'ai fait les corrections des devoirs que vous avez demandées* et *J'ai fait les corrections des devoirs que vous avez demandés* sont toutes deux possibles.

Comment: Effectivement, my bad. La question est tout de même un peu "sèche", il faudrait y rajouter le premier commentaire de @l0r3nz4cc10 (qui fait suite à des commentaires supprimés ? difficile d'y voir clair).

Comment: @guillaume31 Oui, Frank a lâchement effacé ce premier commentaire. Une action en justice me semble justifiée pour rétablir la vérité ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre J'essayais juste de rétablir la vérité en rectifiant un typo! :-)

Comment: @Frank Tu ne pourras le faire qu'en proposant une réponse !

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vraiment nécessaire? Cette question a déjà une réponse pointée par Guillaume.

Comment: @Frank Ben non justement. Lit mon commentaire après lequel guillaume31 a admis qu'il ne s'agissait pas d'un doublon.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai upvoté Anne Aunyme à la place :-) J'ai la flemme ...

Answer (score 2):

D'abord, on fait l'accord du participe passé avec avoir quand il y a un complément obj direct qui précède le participe passé. L'antécédent correspond avec le COD et les deux sont reliés par un pronom relatif.

@Graffiti explique pourquoi il faut faire attention à la sémantique pour trouver l'antécédent du COD et compare la syntaxe et le sens :

> C'est la sémantique qui est pertinente pour trouver l'accord correct.
>
> Exemple 1 :
>
> - **le panier** de pommes qu'il a **rempli** vs
> - le panier de **pommes**
>   qu'il a **cueillies**.
>
> Exemple 2 :
>
> - **le nombre** de pommes qu'il a **estimé** vs
> - le nombre de **pommes** qu'il a **mangées**.

@jlliagre rappelle le fait qu'on ne mange pas trop de nombres.

C'est une bonne habitude de se poser la question, qu'est-ce qu'on a mangé ? Ou qu'est-ce que le sujet a compté ?  Voilà  l'antécédent.  Fais l'accord selon la réponse sémantique de ces questions.

Si on enlève le sujet de la phrase correlative/subordonnée, c'est utile à imaginer le participe passé comme un adjectif par rapport à la transitivité :

- le panier rempli de pommes
- le panier de pommes cueillies
- le nombre estimé de pommes (ou bien le nombre de pommes estimé; on a estimé le nombre, pas les pommes en tout cas)
- le nombre de pommes mangées

Answer (score 1):

Dans le cas de l'auxiliaire "avoir", on ne peut accorder qu'avec un complément direct. On n'accorde que dans certains cas (qu'on peut résumer par "quand le complément est placé avant l'auxiliaire", même si cela est une approximation), mais ici il faut effectivement accorder.

Pour trouver le complément direct, s'il existe, il faut se demander: "qu'est-ce qui est mangé?". Ici, la réponse est simple: les pommes. Le complément direct est donc "les pommes", et il faut écrire "mangé*es*".